# How do I make a state change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made two different components.
in one `v-navigation-drawer`
the second has a button that changes the States of v-navigation-drawer in `vuex`.

When on small screens, there is a call to `v-navigation-drawer`, and after clicking on the gray area, the state in `vuex` does not change.

```
enter code here
```

drawer.vue

```
<template>
    <v-navigation-drawer
        fixed
        :value="drawer"
        app
        :class="getSettingsTheme"
        :mini-variant="mini"
        >
    <b>menu</b>
   </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

sitebar.vue

```
<template>
    <v-toolbar fixed app clipped-right :class="getSettingsTheme">

        <v-tooltip right>
            <v-btn slot="activator" icon @click.stop="drawerMut">
                <v-icon class="theme--light grey--text" color="grey lighten-1">menu</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <span>Show/Hide drawer</span>
    </v-tooltip>

  </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

vuex

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    drawer: true,
},
mutations: {
    drawerMut(state) {
        state.drawer = !state.drawer
    }
},
getters: {
    drawer(state) {
        return state.drawer 
    },
}})
```

Comment: I've never used vue. But my gut would be a that you have to fire off an event in one component and listen to it in the other to refresh the other component.

Comment: Can u add some code?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Have you installed the Vue devtools. You can see if the mutation signal is fired. Then add a console.log in the mutations and set a `watch drawer` in your components and check if the change in the state is reaching the component. Docs for `watch`: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The right decision was at nmanikiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the `drawer` state from the store and update to the store

in Vue we have [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) please go through the docs.

if you use `:value` then on backdrop click the state/value of the `drawer` won't be updated, so use `v-model` with `drawer` as computed with setter and getter.

```js
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        mini: true,
        getSettingsTheme: ''
      }
    }
    computed: {
      drawer: {
        get() {
          return this.$store.getters['drawer'];
        },
        set(val) {
          this.$store.commit('drawerMut', val);
        },
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer fixed
                       v-model="drawer"
                       app
                       :class="getSettingsTheme"
                       :mini-variant="mini">
    <b>menu</b>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

Comment: Found a working example. Can someone come in handy... 
https://codesandbox.io/s/p3q1q08qjq